# Is there a way could keep related route not deleted when interface is down?

Tags: linux, route

I have a specific route(in a policy route table) via a pppoe interface:

```
ppp1      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:61.48.180.187  P-t-P:61.48.180.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:30 (30.0 B)  TX bytes:30 (30.0 B)
```

and

```
$sudo ip route ls table CMCC2
default dev ppp1  scope link
```

Due to some reason, I want to `poff` then `pon` the pppoe interface regularly, but each time after I `poff` the interface the route `default dev ppp1` will be deleted. And after `pon` the interface, I have to manually add it back again. Is there a way to prevent that? I mean deleting the interface `ppp1` but keeping the route `default dev ppp1` not deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a script that runs pon, checks for it's successful completion and then runs the routing command ?

```
#!/bin/bash
pon some parameters || { echo "Failed to bring up PPP link" ; exit 1 ; }
route add some stuff here
```

Comment: I found that after `pon` there is a chance that the interface may not be brought up immediately, and yes, I can wait until it is up, but I thought if there is a way which could keep the route not deleted will be more elegant.

Comment: Stop and think about that for a moment ...